# Detecting to which process a MessageBox belongs

Tags: windows, winapi, popup, messagebox

Is it possible to find out to which process a MessageBox belongs? If yes, how?

Comment: GetWindowThreadProcessId will tell you, but I wonder why you need to know this. You shouldn't be messing with another process's windows. (You wouldn't like it if somebody messed with *your* windows.)

Comment: What is your scenario? Is this for testing or for reverse engineering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `GetWindowThreadProcessId`. Here is an example.

```
#include <windows.h>

static const TCHAR g_cszClass = TEXT("#32770"); // dialog box class

// returned handle must be closed with CloseHandle() when no longer used
HANDLE GetMessageBoxProcess(__in_z LPCTSTR lpcszTitle, __in DWORD dwAccess)
{
  HWND    hWnd;
  DWORD   dwProcessId = 0;
  HANDLE  hRET;

  hWnd = FindWindow(g_cszClass, lpcszTitle);
  if (hWnd != NULL)
  {
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwProcessId);
    if (dwProcessId != 0)
      hRET = OpenProcess(dwAccess, FALSE, dwProcessId);
  }
  return hRET;
}
```

Not sure why you'd want the process though. Reasons I can think of:

- terminating the message box completely
- detecting a process
- detecting a certain message box

all of which have superior & more optimal alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer gives the programmatic solution.  If this is a one-off thing for debugging, you can choose the window with Spy++, get the process ID from the properties window, and then look up the process in Task Manager.